# Show items with no data within slicer values in power bi

Tags: visualization, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have a dataset that contains start and end date for all registers. I have linked end date with my date table, which I use to slice data.

I want to chart how many registers end on each month, however they all end in the same month, and the other months included in the slicer are not shown.

If I select "Show items with no data" then slicer limits are disregarded and all dates are shown, even those outside slicer limits.

I have tried what is explained in [this post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Show-items-with-no-data-not-working-when-slicers-applied/td-p/517689) but I get like circular references and weird errors.

Is there any straightforward way to do that?

**Before -- only columns with data shown:**

[image: before -- only columns with data shown]

**After -- shows too many columns:**

[image: after -- shows too many columns!]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's what I did and it worked 
I said I had a date table -- but it was not set up as a "DATE TABLE" by power BI 
I did it and then the automatic date hierarchy broke down -- so I created a Month column and a year column and when using those in the X axis it behaved correctly, showing only those within the slicer values when selecting "show Items with no data"

[finally it works :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVSlz.png)